# Will unique domain/hard to pronounce cause less visitor

Tags: urls

I bought a domain munucial.com because I named my project "Munucial".

But after registering it I found an issue, though Munucial.com might not be considered a long url since .com can be typed by one key in mobile phones, but the word `Munucial` is quite hard to pronounce.

Will the hard-pronounce url have less visitor then the easy to pronounce url? Since your visitor/user might be hard to talk to someone and tell them to visit munucial.com because they don't know how to pronounce it and the person they're talking too has also no idea to spell it.

So, should I use a hard-pronounce url (munucial.com) for my project/company or a short, easy to remember/spell url (mnc.com)?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of companies are aware that their brand/product might be hard to pronounce so they tend to register multiple domain names.

This to ensure that even users that mispell their domain name are still redirected to the right website.

A quick example that comes to mind is the Compare the Market company, it has two lovable Meerkats as its mascots.

My guess is in order to ensure that their users would find the website they have registered both http://comparethemarket.com and http://comparethemeerkat.com.

Another one is mailchimp, which... has taken it on a whole other level:

https://mailchimp.com/did-you-mean/

Of course beyond the "whimsical factor" these serve as pathways for users to find your website.

A more serious example is Tesla.com and Teslamotors.com. No matter how you know or you have heard of the company you will pretty much end up on the same landing page.

Considering domain names nowadays are fairly cheap, there is no reason not to register both. As a UX dude I am not sure 100% how it affects SEO (if at all) but I can't imagine having two pathways to one website hurts.

The added benefit is that if you register both, overtime you will find out which one works best for you and your product. So when the time comes to renew, you can decide then which one you wish to keep as your main domain.

Comment: Why not register both is because of the short one mnc.com is registered although it's for sale it can't be cheap so I need to decide whether focus on short one or match one